# Boosting my GA with Neural Networks and/or Reinforcement Learning

Tags: java, computer-science, artificial-intelligence, theory, neural-network

As I have mentioned in previous questions I am writing a maze solving application to help me learn about more theoretical CS subjects, after some trouble I've got a Genetic Algorithm working that can evolve a set of rules (handled by boolean values) in order to find a good solution through a maze.

That being said, the GA alone is okay, but I'd like to beef it up with a Neural Network, even though I have no real working knowledge of Neural Networks (no formal theoretical CS education). After doing a bit of reading on the subject I found that a Neural Network could be used to train a genome in order to improve results. Let's say I have a genome (group of genes), such as

```
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0...
```

How could I use a Neural Network (I'm assuming MLP?) to train and improve my genome?

In addition to this as I know nothing about Neural Networks I've been looking into implementing some form of Reinforcement Learning, using my maze matrix (2 dimensional array), although I'm a bit stuck on what the following algorithm wants from me:

(from http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/ReinforcementLearning/Q-Learning-Algorithm.htm)

```
1.  Set parameter , and environment reward matrix R
   2. Initialize matrix Q as zero matrix
   3. For each episode:
          * Select random initial state
          * Do while not reach goal state
                o Select one among all possible actions for the current state
                o Using this possible action, consider to go to the next state
                o Get maximum Q value of this next state based on all possible actions
                o Compute
                o Set the next state as the current state

  End Do

  End For
```

The big problem for me is implementing a reward matrix R and what a Q matrix exactly is, and getting the Q value. I use a multi-dimensional array for my maze and enum states for every move. How would this be used in a Q-Learning algorithm?

If someone could help out by explaining what I would need to do to implement the following, preferably in Java although C# would be nice too, possibly with some source code examples it'd be appreciated.

Comment: This is a very complex subject.  The very things you are talking about are usually addressed in a full semester of a college course in AI.  I'm not sure they can be really addressed properly in a Stackoverflow question an answer, but I'll certainly be interested in seeing people try.  I never did completely wrap my head around some of these algorithms.

Comment: On a side note, if you're willing to spend some cash on a really good text book on the subject then may I suggest: http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Modern-Approach-3rd/dp/0136042597/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1268837913&sr=1-1

Comment: I've glanced at that book a couple of times and although it gives a decent theoretical background of the subject understanding how it can be implemented is killing me. If someone could just write out a basic solution that would work given the information I have provided, even if it is in pseudocode I would be happy enough to try and implement it and give an accepted answer.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a specific maze, or mazes in general?  A simple reinforcement learning algorithm would be able to solve a specific maze, but to solve mazes in general would require a more complex algorithm, specifically probably a more complex state space and possibly action space as well.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Djikstra's algorithm can be used to solve a maze...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in some comments, your question indeed involves a large set of background knowledge and topics that hardly can be eloquently covered on stackoverflow. However, what we can try here is suggest approaches to get around your problem.

First of all: what does your GA do? I see a set of binary values; what are they? I see them as either:

- **bad**: a sequence of 'turn right' and 'turn left' instructions. Why is this bad? Because you're basically doing a random, brute-force attempt at solving your problem. You're not evolving a genotype: you're refining random guesses.
- **better**: every gene (location in the genome) represents a feature that will be expressed in the phenotype. There should not be a 1-to-1 mapping between genome and phenotype!

Let me give you an example: in our brain there are 10^13ish neurons. But we have only around 10^9 genes (yes, it's not an exact value, bear with me for a second). What does this tell us? That our genotype does not encode *every* neuron. Our genome encodes the proteins that will then go and make the components of our body.

Hence, evolution works on the genotype directly by selecting **features** of the phenotype. If I were to have 6 fingers on each hand and if that would made me a better programmer, making me have more kids because I'm more successful in life, well, my genotype would then be selected by evolution because it contains the **capability** to give me a more fit body (yes, there is a pun there, given the average geekiness-to-reproducibily ratio of most people around here).

Now, think about your GA: what is that you are trying to accomplish? Are you sure that evolving rules would help? In other words -- how would **you** perform in a maze? What is the most successful thing that can help you: having a different body, or having a memory of the right path to get out? Perhaps you might want to reconsider your genotype and have it encode *memorization abilities*. Maybe encode in the genotype how much data can be stored, and how fast can your agents access it -- then measure fitness in terms of how fast they get out of the maze. 
Another (weaker) approach could be to encode the rules that your agent uses to decide where to go. The take-home message is, encode features that, once expressed, can be selected by fitness.

---

Now, to the neural network issue. One thing to remember is that NNs are **filters**. They receive an input. perform operations on it, and return an output. What is this output? Maybe you just need to discriminate a true/false condition; for example, once you feed a maze map to a NN, it can tell you if you can get out from the maze or not. How would you do such a thing? You will need to *encode* the data properly.

This is the key point about NNs: your input data must be encoded properly. Usually people normalize it, maybe scale it, perhaps you can apply a sigma function to it to avoid values that are too large or too small; those are details that deal with error measures and performance. What you need to understand now is what a NN is, and what you cannot use it for.

To your problem now. You mentioned you want to use NNs as well: what about,

- using a neural network to guide the agent, and
- using a genetic algorithm to evolve the neural network parameters?

Rephrased like so:

- let's suppose you have a robot: your NN is controlling the left and right wheel, and as input it receives the distance of the next wall and how much it has traveled so far (it's just an example)
- you start by generating a random genotype
- make the genotype into a phenotype: the first gene is the network sensitivity; the second gene encodes the learning ratio; the third gene.. so on and so forth
- now that you have a neural network, run the simulation
- see how it performs
- generate a second random genotype, evolve second NN
- see how this second individual performs
- get the best individual, then either mutate its genotype or recombinate it with the loser
- repeat

there is an **excellent** reading on the matter here: [Inman Harvey Microbial GA](http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/users/inmanh/MicrobialGA_ECAL2009.pdf).

I hope I did you some insight on such issues. NNs and GA are no silver bullet to solve all problems. In some they can do very much, in others they are just the wrong tool. It's (still!) up to us to get the best one, and to do so we must understand them well.

Have fun in it! It's great to know such things, makes everyday life a bit more entertaining :)

Comment: A slight correction. There are about 10^9 base pairs in the human genome. There's somewhere around 20,000 to 25,000 genes. How many of that it takes to build a brain I couldn't say,

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no 'maze gene' to find,

genetic algorithms are trying to setup a vector of properties and a 'filtering system' to decide by some kind of 'surival of the fittest' algorithm to find out which set of properties would do the best job.

The easiest way to find a way out of a maze is to move always left (or right) along a wall.

The Q-Algorithm seems to have a problem with [local maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_minimum) this was workaround as I remember by kicking (adding random values to the matrix) if the results didn't improve.

EDIT: As mentioned above a backtracking algorithm suits this task better than GA or NN.
How to combine both algorithm is described [here](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~omri/NNUGA/) [NeuroGen](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/neurogen.html) descibes how GA is used for training a NN.

Answer (score 0):

- Try using the free open source NerounDotNet C# library for your Neural networks instead of implementing it.
- For Reinforcement Learning library, I am currently looking for one, especially for Dot NET framework..